# Subscribe /tilt_controller1/state to know current position

Tags: ros, callback, state, ros-fuerte, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people,

I am working with Dynamixel Servomotor AX-12+ in ROS fuerte and I need to know its current position.

In my code I subscribe to /tilt_controller1/state this is the info topic:

```
youbot@diego-VPCEH2K1E:~$ rostopic info /tilt_controller1/state
Type: dynamixel_msgs/JointState
```

but I dont know how to put the arguments of the callback, this is my code:

```
#include <dynamixel_msgs/JointState.h>
//----------------
void callback(const dynamixel_msgs::JointState& str)
{
    //str.current_pos
    std::cout<<"rotacion"<<std::endl;
}
//-------
sub = n.subscribe("/tilt_controller1/state", 1, callback);
```

The error is:

fatal error: dynamixel_msgs/JointState.h: No such file or directory

I think is a mistake with the library...is the rest of the code ok? Please can somebody help me?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213258/subscribe-/tilt_controller1/state-to-know-current-position/) by [Rookie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/18371/rookie92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2015-07-09**:
Could you elaborate? I'm not sure I completely understand your question. If this doesn't compile, please update your question with the compiler output and error messages.

**Comment by [Rookie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/18371/rookie92/) on 2015-07-09**:
Eddit with the error. I think I have not the library JointState.h but i dont know if that is the only problem. Where can i get the library and where must i put it? I add in the manifest:

```
<depend package="JointState"/>
```

and then this is the error:

1/2

**Comment by [Rookie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/18371/rookie92/) on 2015-07-09**:
2/2

and then this is the error:

```
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests mapping
  [rospack] Error: package/stack mapping depends on non-existent package JointState
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package is actually [dynamixel_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_msgs?distro=fuerte). JointState is one of the messages defined in the dynamixel_msgs package, so change

```
<depend package="JointState"/>
```

to

```
<depend package="dynamixel_msgs"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rookie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/18371/rookie92/) on 2015-07-10**:
Thanks so much tbh!!!!! you have made me happier Friday :)

Only one question more in the callback when i want to use the current position is this code line right?

```
counter=str.current_pos;
```

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2015-07-10**:
Sure thing. That looks right to me.

**Comment by [Rookie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/18371/rookie92/) on 2015-07-10**:
Thanks thanks thanks thanks!!!!!